# Refresh PHP file on page when file changed

Tags: php

I have made a very successful PHP chat box that saves the chat to a text file. I'm almost done with it except for the fact that I have to have it for user #2 when user #1 sends a message. I have looked into AJAX but I'm not using any JavaScript so I think it would be hard to put it in my script. I don't want the page or iframe or anything to be refreshed until a new message (file updated) had appeared.

Comment: In short: You cannot refresh the clients browser from server side. Either the user reloads the window manually, or you use javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you can afford to use HTML5, then **HTML5 - WebSockets** is the way forward for your project.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a server-side language. You would be required to use javascript or alike for interaction from the browser outside of the PHP script.

In your PHP script, if you echo the following to User2, it will cause their browser to refresh the current page:

```
<script>window.location.reload();</script>
```

Or you can do the following to refresh the page every, say, 60 seconds:

```
<script>setTimeout( window.location.reload()", 60*1000 );</script>
```

Comment: I have these already... There is no way to have it refresh showing the file just when it changed? Not just refresh because right now I have it in a iframe and it refreshes that so it doesn't mess up the users when they are typing. User #2 will type to User #1 and there will be more than just 2 people I was just saying that to give an example.

Comment: PHP is not designed for that. You should really implement it the correct way by using AJAX/REST/WebSockets, etc.